# Facebook Java API, sending app-to-user notification

Tags: java, facebook, notifications

I'm trying to get this to work. This is my utility method for sending an app-to-user notification to a single user. Session id is not needed for that.

```
public Collection<String> notifyUser(String user, String msg) throws FacebookException
{
    FacebookJsonRestClient fbkClient = new FacebookJsonRestClient(FacebookUtil.appApiKey, FacebookUtil.appSecret);
    List<Long> recipients = new ArrayList<Long>();
    recipients.add(new Long(user));

    return fbkClient.notifications_send(recipients, msg, true);
}
```

I'm trying it with my user id. I never get the notification, and the returned collection is empty (should be a list of users who were effectively notified).

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API is deprecated.  You should use a newer technique for sending "invites".

Here's how to send app requests to users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

But you might be best off using the new object/actions as described here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: Sorry, I've been absent for a while!

Answer (score 0):

notifications where disabled from facebook apps